# Can I still merge and push to the repository even if the state was forcefully changed to public?

Tags: merge, mercurial

So, I'm new to Mercurial, and on my first try I screwed up.

Before pushing my data, I tried to merge with one branch (which I think was an old branch)

Instead of pushing it properly to change from "draft" to "public" I manually changed it from Tortoise by using the change phase from "draft" to "public"

I thought it meant that it would be placed in the repository, but when I went to the actual repository (on Bit Bucket) I couldn't find it.

So what happened, is I think I never made a push.

This is causing me an issue to make new changes, because when I tried committing other files, merging it with other branches and pushing it to the repository, i get the error:

```
searching for changes
remote has heads on branch 'branch one' that are not known locally: 62bf86f93d4f
abort: push creates new remote head 7edef5d2e2e5 on branch 'branch one'!
hint: pull and merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads
[command returned code 255 Thu May 27 14:43:44 2015]
```

So I think the solution would be to merge with the original draft (which is now public)

Thus my question: Is it possible to still merge and push a revision that was already deemed "public", even if I can't find it in the repository on bitbucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phase of your commit (public vs. draft vs. secret) has no relevance for whether the commit can be merged. The difference between draft and public only affects whether the history involving the commit can be altered (e.g. via `hg commit --amend` or `hg rebase`). Public revisions are considered immutable, draft revisions can still be altered.

You can still merge and push. In theory, if you are positive that you didn't push the commit, you can also safely change the phase back to draft. However, that would be pointless [1], because pushing the merge will immediately make it public again [2].

[1] It can be useful if you use `hg pull --rebase`, but if you don't know what that does, you probably shouldn't use it.

[2] Unless you push to a non-publishing repository, but that's unlikely unless your group is using the evolve extension. If you don't know what a non-publishing repository or the evolve extension is, you don't need to know.